# Deducing the Gaussian Formula

Tags: combinatorics

How would one prove the following formula: For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \binom{n}{m}_q = \begin{cases} \displaystyle \mathop{\prod_{k \text{ odd}}}_{1 \le k\leq n} (1-q^k), & \text{if } n \text{ is even}\\[30pt]0, &\text{if } n \text{ is odd}. \end{cases}$$

I know the odd case follows swiftly from the symmetry property of $q$-binomial coefficients, but I am having trouble working out the even case. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recurrence of the $q-$ binomial coefficients gives $\binom{2n}{m}_q$= $q^m \binom{2n-1}{m}_q+ \binom{2n-1}{m-1}_q$ and therefore $\sum_{m=0}^{2n} (-1)^m \binom{2n}{m}_q =\sum_{m=0}^{2n-1} (-1)^m q^m\binom{2n-1}{m}_q .$
Formula $(1-q^m) \binom{2n-1}{m}_q=(1-q^{2n-1}) \binom{2n-2}{m-1}_q $ implies therefore
$ \sum_{m=0}^{2n} (-1)^m \binom{2n}{m}_q =(1-q^{2n-1})\sum_{m=0}^{2n-2} (-1)^{m-1}\binom{2n-2}{m-1}_q .$

**Edit**

A more elegant proof is the following: Let $r(n)=\sum_{m=0}^n (-1)^m \binom{n}{m}_q.$

Consider the $q-$ exponential function $e(x) = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{{x^n}}}{{(1 - q) \cdots (1 - {q^n})}}} .$

Comparing coefficients gives $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{r(n)}}{{(1 - q) \cdots (1 - {q^n})}}}  = e( - x)e(x).$

Now  $e(x) = \frac{1}{{(1 - x)(1 - qx)(1 - {q^2}x) \cdots }}$ and therefore  $e( - x)e(x) = \frac{1}{{(1 - {x^2})(1 - {q^2}{x^2})(1 - {q^4}{x^2}) \cdots }} = \sum\limits_{}^{} {\frac{{{x^{2n}}}}{{(1 - {q^2})(1 - {q^4}) \cdots (1 - {q^{2n}})}}.} $

Comparing coefficients of the last two series gives

$r(2n) = \frac{{(1 - q)(1 - {q^2}) \cdots (1 - {q^{2n}})}}{{(1 - {q^2})(1 - {q^4}) \cdots (1 - {q^{2n}})}} = (1 - q)(1 - {q^3}) \cdots (1 - {q^{2n - 1}}).$

Answer (score 2):

Let $F(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\binom{n}{k}_q$.

It should be obvious, by symmetry, that $F(n)=0$ when $n$ is odd.

When $n$ is even, say $n=2m$, we write

$$
\begin{align}
F(2m)
  &= \sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k \binom{2m}k_q
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^{2m} (-1)^k \left[\binom{2m-1}{k-1}_q+q^k\binom{2m-1}{k}_q\right]
&&(q-\text{Pascal identity})
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{2m} (-1)^k \binom{2m-1}{k-1}_q+\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^kq^k\binom{2m-1}{k}_q
\\&= \sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^{k+1} \binom{2m-1}{k}_q+\sum_{k=0}^{2m-1} (-1)^kq^k\binom{2m-1}{k}_q 
&& (\text{re-index first sum})
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} (-1)^k\binom{2m-1}{k}_q(q^k-1)
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} (-1)^k\binom{2m-2}{k-1}_q(q^{2m-1}-1) 
&& (\text{See below})
\\&= (1-q^{2m-1})\sum_{k=1}^{2m-1} (-1)^{k-1}\binom{2m-2}{k-1}_q 
\\&= (1-q^{2m-1})\sum_{k=0}^{2m-2} (-1)^{k}\binom{2m-2}{k}_q 
\\&= (1-q^{2m-1})\cdot F(2m-2)
\end{align}
$$
The final equation, $$F(2m)=(1-q^{2m-1})F(2m-2),$$ quickly leads to a proof by induction that $F(2m)=(1-q^{2m-1})(1-q^{2m-3})\cdots (1-q)$ for all integers $m\ge 0$.

In the second-to-last step, I used the identity
$$
\binom{2m-1}k_q(q^k-1)=\binom{2m-2}{k-1}_q (q^{2m-1}-1)
$$
This is the $q$-variant of the absorption identity for the binomial coefficients, $\binom{2m-1}{k}\cdot k=\binom{2m-2}{k-1}\cdot (2m-1)$. The proof is as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\require{cancel}
\binom{2m-1}k_q(q^k-1)
&=\frac{(q^{2m-1}-1)(q^{2n-2}-1)\cdots (q-1)}{\cancel{(q^k-1)}(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots (q-1)(q^{2m-1-k}-1)\cdots (q-1)}\cdot \cancel{(q^k-1)}
\\
&=\frac{(q^{2m-2}-1)(q^{2m-3}-1)\cdots (q-1)}{(q^{k-1}-1)\cdots (q-1)(q^{2m-1-k}-1)\cdots (q-1)}\cdot (q^{2m-1}-1)
\\
&= \binom{2m-2}{k-1}_q (q^{2m-1}-1).
\end{align}
$$